# Embed YouTube Video in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, youtube, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone app development and I would like to know what is the best way to embed YouTube videos in Windows Phone 8 App? I would like to provide a list of videos with thumbnails and user should be able to click and watch the video just like any typical app.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try using the YouTube Api? sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Youtube-Video-Sample-f2692dc9

Answer (score 1):

I had tried some third party SDKs while I was doing this for Windows 8 but was not happy with any of the solutions.

Finally I resorted to embedding the video in a Web View control and the output was pretty desirable. I have not tried this on Windows Phone but should work as it did on Windows 8 since the underlying browser is the same. Try it out:-

```
string html = @"<style> body{margin:0; padding:0;} iframe{width:100%;height:480px;}@media screen and (max-width:300px) { iframe{width:100%;height:180px;}}  </style><iframe style=""padding:0px;margin-bottom:-20px;""   src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + @"?rel=0"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
videoView.NavigateToString(html);
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. Is it possible to track at what point user paused the video so that I can store the time and provide "resume" option. Can I use YouTube Player API with this approach on Windows Phone?

Comment: I doubt it because once you embed the video, I think you handover all control to google to display and play the video. I might be wrong though

Comment: it would only work if you add <!DOCTYPE html> to the start of the html

Answer (score 0):

First try creating sample video application in [Windows Phone App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us?stay=) which uses YouTube API services and display videos in application.

Download the source code and refer, How it uses YouTube API services and gets video. Source code will be in MVVM pattern and its the best way to implement. You may get some basic knowledge on how to develop apps that uses YouTube services.

You can refer the [source code](http://1drv.ms/1uas0md) which uses YouTube API services, which I generated for more information.